# How do I make sure that data is passed correctly in d3 on drag?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a d3 chart where a user can drag some points along the y axis.

What I am trying to do is to update the original data array to include the user's updated choice for any value represented on that chart.

here is the drag function:

```
function dragged( e ) {
            let yLocation = d3.event.y;

            let index;
            for ( index = 0; index < data.length && data[ index ][ 'x' ] !== e.x; index++ ) {
            }
            data[ index ][ 'y' ] = (y.invert(d3.mouse(this)[ 1 ]));

            d3.select(this).select("circle")
              .attr("cy", e.y = yLocation);

            update(data);
        }
```

my problem is when trying to update the value in the array:

```
data[ index ][ 'y' ] = (y.invert(d3.mouse(this)[ 1 ]));
```

If I try and log `(y.invert(d3.mouse(this)[ 1 ]))`, the correct value(value corresponding to position of mouse) is displayed, however if I try to log the data array, the object is updated with the position of the mouse instead of the value corresponding to that position.

Should I use promises to control the values, before updating the array of objects? Or is there a better solution? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you attempting to do with this line:

```
d3.select(this).select("circle")
 .attr("cy", e.y = yLocation);
```

`e` here is the datum object in the array.  By setting `e.y` to `yLocation`, you are updating the array datum's y value to the mouse location.  **Remember** that when you pass a JavaScript object into a function it is a *reference* to the object (meaning it's the same object).  This means you don't need to search and update your data array, you already have the part of it you want!

The correct code here (untested, of course) is:

```
let yLocation = d3.event.y;
e.y = y.invert(d3.mouse(this)[ 1 ]);
d3.select(this).select("circle")
  .attr("cy", yLocation);
```